# Twig syntax highlighting sublime text

Tags: sublimetext2, twig, syntax-highlighting

I want to know how can I have **highlighting syntax for TWIG** in Sublime Text.
Actually when I open a TWIG file all fonctions and conditions are similar (white on black) :
[image: Screenshot SublimeText2]

Answer (score 110, accepted):

### Documentation

Syntax highlighting and auto-completion for Twig in Sublime Text 2
is possible with : **PHP-Twig.tmbundle**

- TWIG Doc "IDEs Integration" : http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#ides-integration
- Bundle's Github : https://github.com/Anomareh/PHP-Twig.tmbundle
- Bundle's Documentation : https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/PHP-Twig

### Download

You can clone the project with :

```
git clone https://github.com/Anomareh/PHP-Twig.tmbundle.git
```

Or download it directly from the Github (*last master version*) : 
https://github.com/Anomareh/PHP-Twig.tmbundle/archive/master.zip

### Installation

To install this bundle in Sublime Text, a few extra steps are required.

1. Open Sublime Text and in the **Preferences** menu click **Browse Packages**.
2. In the directory that was just opened, create a new directory `PHP-Twig/`.
3. Copy the content of this repo into the directory you just created.
4. Move the contents of the `PHP-Twig/Syntaxes/` directory to `PHP-Twig/`
5. Restart Sublime Text.

### Apply

To apply syntax highlighting on your Twig HTML files :

1. Open a `.html.twig` file
2. Go to **View** menu → **Syntax** → **Open all with current extension as** → **HTML (Twig)**

That’s it. It should work by now.

### Screenshot

[image: Twig syntax highlighting sublime text 2]

Comment: This solution still works well on Sublime Text 3. In case, someone is looking solution for ST3.

Comment: Can you clone it directly to the Sublime Packages directory?

Comment: I only needed to copy the package file `PHP-Twig.tmbundle` into the packages directory for Sublime Text 3.

Comment: I cant find the apply section in the github. Thanks god this answer provides

Answer (score 47):

You can also install **PHP-Twig.tmbundle** through Sublime Text's [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/installation#st2).

With **Package Control** installed:

1. Go to **Preferences** → **Package Control** → **Install Package**
2. Type "Twig", and select **PHP-Twig**.

It will install the same version of [@antoine-subit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26294306/2432027), and will automatically use the correct syntax for any Twig file you open

Comment: I am using sublime 3.2.2 version, this worked for me. Thanks dear.

Answer (score 13):

If you're not used to Sublime, don't forget to click on the bottom right of the sublime window (a drop up/down should appear) and then select "HTML (Twig)" from the list of languages in order to enable the package!

Comment: Thanks, Mr. @user2511803 ! I was searching for Twig, instead of HTML (Twig). Fistbump.

Comment: Installed this, uninstalled it, and then reinstalled after reading this comment.  Should be mentioned in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on Ubuntu, I have solved the problem by downloading https://github.com/Anomareh/PHP-Twig.tmbundle/archive/master.zip and I have done what was wrote inside ReadMe file.

- After restarting Sublime Text choose the option called “HTML (Twig)” in “View->Syntax” menu to see the new highlighting.
- To automatically highlight all twig files, open any html.twig template and select
  “View->Syntax->Open all current extension as…->HTML (Twig)”